# Chevy C1500 89 turns off when put into drive gear

Tags: chevrolet

At first it was not turning on because of injector not working and got the problem fixed. The fuel pump, ignition coil, spark plugs, and spark plug wires also got changed. Now the current problem that it has is that when put into gear Drive, the truck turns off. I got the catalytic converters pipes loose to see if that would be the problem but it was the same issue. What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "turns off" here?  Do you mean the engine stalls or do you mean that it's like turning the ignition key off and all power is gone?

Comment: Also, for reference sake, is this a K1500 or C1500? If it is just "shutting off" (like turning the ignition switch), I'd suggest there's probably an issue in the column which is killing the ignition power source. Just a guess, though.

Comment: I dont know if its an ignition switch issue, but it feels like the engine jumps a bit and doesnt have enough power to run. It stays running in park but when I switch to drive the engine shuts off. I think is better if I make a video.

Comment: This sounds like you might have a vacuum leak below the throttle body. If the throttle body was changed out or there was work done where it had to be removed, I'm thinking your issue may lie there.